# Why do I have to override my init in Swift now?

Tags: swift, initialization, overriding

```
import Foundation

class Student: NSObject
{
    var name: String
    var year: Int
    var major: String
    var gpa : String

    init(name:String, year:Int, major:String, gpa:String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
    }

    convenience init()
    {
        //calls longer init method written above
    }
}
```

--

The error shows itself atthe line of the convenience init

> Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword

I've tried Googling this and reading guides on initializers in Swift, but it seems like they were able to make their initializers just fine without overriding anything.

Comment: One thing that can be confusing about this error (well, it confused me for a while) is the following scenario: Usually you have additional stored properties in your derived classes, so your init() includes parameters for them, and a call to super.init() for the base class's stored properties. No "override" is needed. But then one day you happen to create a derived class with no additional stored properties, and you write your init() the way you usually do, but now suddenly Swift is nagging you for an "override" keyword. That's because now the init() signature matches the one in the base class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it looks like your convenience initializer is empty which is why you get the error. For example if you change it to:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(name: "", year: 0, major: "nothing", gpa: "4.0")
}
```

the error would go away.

I wonder why you set up Student to inherit from NSObject. It doesn't look necessary for your class.

Comment: He's not conforming to `NSObject`.  He's inheriting from `NSObject` class.

Comment: Yes sorry about the confusion. I edited my original post.

Comment: I was told I needed to but it appears that's not the case; thank you!

Answer (score 7):

`init` is a designated initializer for `NSObject`. If you override it, you must mark this as `override` and call a superclass designated initializer. This follows the [normal rules for initializer inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216).